# How to implement stable ids on a custom cursor adapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-checkbox

I have a list view where each row is a checkbox. In order to know the rows selected I think using stable ids will help me out. But I haven't found any tutorial or example that can help me. Any suggestions? I'm currently overriding the bindView and newView for recycling purposes.

Comment: providing more info. will help. What is your exact problem and what problem you are facing in implementing that.

Comment: I need to store in a database the checkboxes selected. And I would like to do it from the oncreate method since I have a button on my main fragment. Then I guess using the method lv.getCheckedItemIds() I can recover this items. Im not sure how to set the stable ids in my custom adapter, so I can store the id of my checkbox from database. Maybe is there a better way, I dont know. I'm kind of new with android.

Comment: Note that since I'm overriding the bindView and newView methods, I'm not using the position at all. I rather prefer get the id of the items than I'm showing with check boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Create your table with `_id` column and use that as the id. [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html)

Answer (score 1):

just use getPosition() in the getView() and call setTag((Integer)cursor.getPosition()) on the parent view, you can then handle it in onItemClickListener, just use getTag() to pull the position, and then look it up in the cursor.

Comment: Thanks for the answering but that doesn't answer my question. And I'm not using getView(), I'm using newView() and bindView(). From here I have no access to the position. I just want to know how to use stable ids.

Comment: The position is probably a stable id, and you have access to it in bindView and newView and you can still use getTag/setTag.

Otherwise, just add a _id column to your database like others have said.